# Java - Store last characters in array

Tags: java, arrays

Is it possible to store the last characters from a string in an array as a double?

I have following string:

```
String s="random number 230";
```

That means I would like to have the array to look like this:

```
double array[] = {230}
```

Comment: arrays don't look like that. Do you want an array of `{2,3,0}`?

Comment: Does `String.format` help you?

Comment: So in java you can use split method with separator " " and get an array of three strings and you can get the 230 value by accessing the second value of the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are looking for, but based entirely on the example you gave, you could use this:

```
String[] words = s.split(" ");
String numberString = words[words.length-1];

try{
    double[] array = new double[]{Double.parseDouble(numberString)};
}
catch(NumberFormatException e){

    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Explanation:

`.split` turns a string into an array of strings based on some delimiter.

I used a blank space (i.e. `" "`).

Then, I reference the last string in the array as `numberString`. The array size will only be `0` if `s` is an empty string (which would be a different problem).

And then I use `Double.parseDouble()` which **tries** to return a `double` value represented in a string. The `try\catch` block means that we are prepared that it might not work.

More information on that last bit can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble-java.lang.String-)